# dnf no longer work after upgrade to fedora 33 from 32

Tags: python, fedora, dnf

Follow [this manual](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/dnf-system-upgrade/) to upgrade fedora from 32 to 33. After reboot, when run `dnf check-update`, the following error
occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dnf", line 57, in <module>
    from dnf.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dnf'
```

Additional Information:

The output of command `rpm -qa python3` is:

```
python3-3.9.1-2.fc33.x86_64
python3-3.8.7-2.fc32.x86_64
```

It seems that even after upgrade to fedora 33, old fedora 32 packages are still there.
Run `rpm -qa | sort` proved that.

The output of command `rpm -ql python3-3.8.7-2.fc32.x86_64` is:

```
/usr/bin/pydoc
/usr/bin/pydoc3
/usr/bin/pydoc3.8
/usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3.8
/usr/lib/.build-id
/usr/lib/.build-id/da
/usr/lib/.build-id/da/2e3a5d2a850e1b6e560df11fa5d61a7192f954
/usr/share/doc/python3
/usr/share/doc/python3/README.rst
/usr/share/man/man1/python3.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/python3.8.1.gz
```

But the output of `python3-3.8.7-2.fc33.x86_6` is:

```
error: open of python3-3.8.7-2.fc33.x86_64 failed: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You probably will have more luck with this question on SuperUser or ServerFault

Comment: Can you import `dnf` when running `python3.8`? E.g., `python3.8 -c "import dnf"`, as well as `python3.8 -c "import dnf.cli"`.

Comment: @mousetail. I realize that I should have posted it on ServerFault, but I cannot move it to ServerFault. So I voted to close and move it to ServerFault.